# Lazy loading in Angular 6 resulting in Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to achieve lazy loading in my Angular app.
Here are my routes:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './customer/customer.module#CustomerModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

and in module:

```
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
```

**customer-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ComparePageComponent },
  { path: 'funds', component: FundSelectionComponent },
  { path: ':service', component: ComparePageComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

and in module :

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
```

Now, I have a logic that will load the `/profile` page when there are no path params i.e. when the url is '' (`this._router.navigate(['', 'profile'])`) for which I have already defined a path in my customer module `{ path: ':service', component: ComparePageComponent }`

But, when the app runs, it results in the following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'profile' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'profile'
>       at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirect

Not really sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: how does profile and service are related?

Comment: @Sajeetharan profile is the path param in the url. service is the placeholder for the path param that I have specified as :service

Comment: @SiddAjmera, that's happening for the /funds path as well. It is not taking any of the paths mentioned in the customer module

Comment: @SiddAjmera, you mean to say I must have a component for the empty route in the app-routing.module.ts?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes, I am

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `AppRoutingModule` just has one route that loads the `CustomerModule` for the user. But that too on an empty route(`''`).

But when you navigate the user to the `/profile` route, Angular is looking for a config corresponding to the `'profile'` path in your AppRoutingModule.

But since it's not able to find it there, it's throwing this error.

To make Angular look beyond the empty path(`''`), it needs to use the `prefix` `pathMatch` strategy, which is used by default unless you specify it as `full`.

You might want to try removing the `pathMatch: 'full'` from your route config in the AppRoutingModule in order to fix it.

Comment: Removing pathMatch: 'full' from AppRoutingModule and adding it to CustomerRoutingModule fixed the issue

Comment: What is the best best practice when it comes to providing empty paths?? Should we use pathMatch in AppRoutingModule or the FeatureRoutingModule??

I just want to make sure I am following best practices.

Comment: It depends on the requirement. There's isn't any laid or fixed best practice for using `pathMatch`. In this case, we wanted Angular to check for `prefix`es rather than the complete `path`. Hence we should not have specified the `path` as its value by default is `prefix` unless specified as `full`

Answer (score 1):

You have issue the navigation path. You should start the navigation from the `root` by using `/`

`this._router.navigate(['/', 'profile']))`

Comment: this didn't help

Comment: Is customer module path `'./customer/customer.module#CustomerModule'` right ?

Comment: Yes, that's the path

Comment: Can you check if `this._router.navigate(['/funds']))`  working?

Comment: got the answer from @SiddAjmera's post. Thank you